# CentOS 7 LDAP Authentication: "Permission denied"

Tags: active-directory, ldap, centos7, pam-ldap

I'm running a CentOS 7 VirtualBox instance. I am trying to set up LDAP authentication through our company Active Directory server.

Note: The AD server DOES NOT have Unix extensions installed.

Setup:

- I have nss-pam-ldapd installed
- The nslcd and nscd services are set to run at startup
- /etc/nsswitch.conf has been edited to add ldap:

  ```
  passwd:     files ldap
  group:      files ldap
  shadow:     files ldap 
  hosts:      files ldap dns myhostname
  ethers:     files ldap
  networks:   files ldap
  protocols:  files ldap
  rpc:        files ldap
  services:   files ldap sss
  aliases:    files ldap nisplus
  ```
- /etc/pam.d/password-auth and /etc/pam.d/system-auth edited to add:

  ```
  auth     sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pas
  account  [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
  password sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authok
  session  optional      pam_ldap
  session  required      pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0077
  ```
- /etc/nslcd.conf edited:

  ```
  uid nslcd
  gid nslcd

  uri ldap://myserver.com/

  base dc=myserver,dc=com

  binddn CN=My Name,OU=Users,OU=DV,DC=myserver,DC=com

  bindpw PASSWORDHERE

  # Alternative mappings for Active Directory
  pagesize 1000
  referrals off
  idle_timelimit 800
  filter passwd (&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer)))
  map    passwd uid           userPrincipalName
  map    passwd uidNumber     objectSid:CorrectSID
  map    passwd gidNumber     objectSid:CorrectSID
  map    passwd homeDirectory "/home/$cn"
  map    passwd gecos         displayName
  map    passwd loginShell    "/bin/bash"
  filter group (objectClass=group)
  map    group gidNumber      objectSid:CorrectSID
  ssl no
  ```

On rebooting the VM, and remoting in with the default user, I can list all the AD users (user@myserver.com), and the groups, using

```
    $ getent passwd
    and
    $ getent group
```

However, if I attempt to either login to the GUI or remote in with my AD user:

```
    $ ssh my.name@myserver.com@linuxboxip
    my.name@myserver.com@linuxboxip's password:
    Permission denied, please try again.
```

I've been over the related questions on this site, through the debug, and reconfigured fresh from scratch. No luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd work with your systems adminstration group...your system might be restricted administratively from getting to the AD.

Comment: I'll look into it, but I'm betting it is not the problem. I can see all the users and groups in the AD inside the Linux instance using getent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem.

See [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/588180/ldap-login-fails-but-su-to-ldap-users-works)

When editing the PAM files: /etc/pam.d/password-auth and /etc/pam.d/system-auth

The edits must be done to the appropriate sections, not just added to the bottom of the file. In particular, the `password    required      pam_deny.so` lines MUST be the LAST entry in the section.

I can now log in with LDAP user/password via SSH and the GUI.