# Centos 7 LDAP Authentication (su works but ssh/console login not works)

Tags: centos, ldap

I have Centos 7 and next installed packages:

```
[root@centos7 pam.d]# rpm -qa|grep ldap
nss-pam-ldapd-0.8.13-8.el7.x86_64
openldap-2.4.44-5.el7.x86_64
openldap-clients-2.4.44-5.el7.x86_64
```

My configs:

**/etc/nslcd.conf:**

```
uid nslcd
gid ldap

uri ldap://<my_ldap_server_ip>

base dc=company,dc=org

binddn cn=proxy,ou=users,dc=company,dc=org
bindpw <bind_pw>

nss_initgroups_ignoreusers root,nslcd
nss_min_uid 10000

filter passwd (objectClass=posixAccount)
base passwd ou=users,dc=company,dc=org
base shadow ou=users,dc=company,dc=org
base group ou=groups,dc=company,dc=org
scope passwd one
scope shadow one
scope group one

map group member uniqueMember

ssl start_tls
TLS_REQCERT allow
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
```

**/etc/nsswitch:**

```
. . .
passwd:     files sss ldap
shadow:     files sss ldap
group:      files sss ldap
. . .
```

**/etc/pam.d/:**

```
[root@centos7 pam.d]# ls -lah password-auth system-auth
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 Aug 22 18:53 password-auth -> password-auth-ac
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 Aug 22 18:53 system-auth -> system-auth-ac
```

**/etc/pam.d/password-auth:**

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so
password    required      pam_deny.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
password    required      pam_deny.so
```

**/etc/system-auth:**

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so
password    required      pam_deny.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
password    required      pam_deny.so
```

When I'm doing 'su - ldapuser' I've entered.

But from ssh/console I can't login.

**nslcd -d:**

```
nslcd: [e2a9e3] DEBUG: connection from pid=4867 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [e2a9e3] <passwd="ldapuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=company,dc=org", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=ldapuser))")
nslcd: [e2a9e3] <passwd="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=ldapuser,ou=users,dc=company,dc=org
nslcd: [e2a9e3] <passwd="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [45e146] DEBUG: connection from pid=4867 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [45e146] <passwd="ldapuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=company,dc=org", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=ldapuser))")
nslcd: [45e146] <passwd="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=ldapuser,ou=users,dc=company,dc=org
nslcd: [45e146] <passwd="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [5f007c] DEBUG: connection from pid=4867 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [5f007c] <passwd="ldapuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=company,dc=org", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=ldapuser))")
nslcd: [5f007c] <passwd="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=ldapuser,ou=users,dc=company,dc=org
nslcd: [5f007c] <passwd="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [d062c2] DEBUG: connection from pid=4867 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [d062c2] <passwd="ldapuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=company,dc=org", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=ldapuser))")
nslcd: [d062c2] <passwd="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=ldapuser,ou=users,dc=company,dc=org
nslcd: [d062c2] <passwd="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [200854] DEBUG: connection from pid=4867 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: nslcd_pam_authc("ldapuser","sshd","***")
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=company,dc=org", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=ldapuser))")
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=ldapuser,ou=users,dc=company,dc=org
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="cn=ldapuser,ou=users,dc=company,dc=org", filter="(objectClass=*)")
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://<my_ldap_server_ip>)
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,30)
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,30)
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,30)
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_start_tls_s()
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: set_socket_timeout(30,500000)
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=ldapuser,ou=users,dc=company,dc=org","***") (uri="ldap://<my_ldap_server_ip>")
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> ldap_result() failed: No such object
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> cn=ldapuser,ou=users,dc=company,dc=org: lookup failed: No such object
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: set_socket_timeout(15,0)
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_unbind()
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=users,dc=company,dc=org", filter="(&(objectClass=shadowAccount)(uid=ldapuser))")
nslcd: [200854] <authc="ldapuser"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
```

**journalctl -xlf:**

```
Feb 20 20:37:24 centos7.localdomain sshd[4965]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.56.1  user=ldapuser
Feb 20 20:37:24 centos7.localdomain sshd[4965]: pam_ldap(sshd:auth): Authentication failure; user=ldapuser
Feb 20 20:37:26 centos7.localdomain sshd[4965]: Failed password for goncharuk from 192.168.56.1 port 56663 ssh2
```

**UPD:** I forgot show this links:
I've read this topics and they not help me:

[centos-7-ldap-authentication-permission-denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/833056/centos-7-ldap-authentication-permission-denied)

[ldap-login-fails-but-su-to-ldap-users-works](https://serverfault.com/questions/588180/ldap-login-fails-but-su-to-ldap-users-works)

Comment: Why didn't you just use sssd

Comment: See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/sssd-ad

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I need to use nslcd.

Comment: I have this working without issue, however I used authconfig-gtk to get it going.

Comment: I used authconfig (cli) and authconfig-tui(ncurses) too. But it's not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the problem has been solved.

Some brief before concrete steps. Anyone knowns that LDAP login procedure followed this steps:

Authentification:

1. Connecting to LDAP server.
2. 'Bind'-ing as 'search-user'.
3. Searching necessary user.
4. 'Bind'-ing as user from step 3 with corresponding password.

Authorization:

5. Searching needed attributes.
6. Login

If login is incorrect on step 3, then 'User not found' message produced.

If password on step 4 is incorrect, then 'Invalid credentials' message produced.

Indeed, NSLCD do all these steps.

Step 4 in NSLCD have one improvement about security reasons. After 'bind'-ing as found user, NSLCD trying search in user 'DN' with base as 'DN' to ensure that this 'DN' is really 'DN' of 'bind'-ing user. For instance ('ldapsearch' request):

```
ldapsearch -w <user_passwd> -h <ldap_server_ip> -D "cn=ldapuser,ou=users,dc=company,dc=org" -b "cn=ldapuser,ou=users,dc=company,dc=org"
```

This behaviour was described by author of nss-pam-ldapd in at least this sources:

[issue 1](https://lists.arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd-users/2017/msg00070.html)

[issue 2](https://lists.arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd-users/2016/msg00025.html)

**This mean that user which want to be logged in over NSLCD must have search permissions in own LDAP 'DN'!**

In NSLCD versions before 0.9.x this behaviour was not changeable.

In NSLCD version that begins from 0.9.x it's possible to skip search in own 'DN' via **'pam_authc_search NONE'** option.

In my case, using 'pam_authc_search NONE' really help me, but it's need to build and install 'nss-pam-ldapd' package with new version. Now, I am testing LDAP login on VM with Centos 7. I have at least 5 different distros and building packages for each is not good solution. In addition, two-phactor login checks (bind + search) is really need security tool. So, I changed my LDAP server (OpenLDAP 2.4) ACL-s to grand search access for users in own 'DN' and now all works fine:

/etc/openldap/slapd.conf:

```
. . .
access to attrs=userPassword
        by self read
        by anonymous auth
        by * none

access to *
        by self read
        by dn="cn=searchuser,ou=users,dc=company,dc=org" read
        by * none
. . .
```